# Discord.py: Can you verify what command check failed in a CheckFailure error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it is possible to verify which check failed when a CheckError is thrown? I've looked at the documentation and don't see any way to retrieve that information. When a CheckError occurs in my bot the error is too generic and says `The check functions for command X failed.`

I want to verify which check failed so I can send specific messages to the user based on different check failures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Far from the most elegant solution, but if you have custom checks you can throw a CheckError manually if the check is failing. Here's an example:

```
def is_user_currently_using_command(ongoing_member_commands):
async def predicate(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in ongoing_member_commands:
        raise commands.CheckFailure("Member has already started a receipt upload.")
    
    return True
    
return commands.check(predicate)
```

Then when handling CheckErrors you can check the error's arguments for that specific text. It's not great, but it does work.